# Postgresql logical replication, duplicate key errors on subscriber

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am still quite new to postgres logical replication and am having trouble when replicating a large data set.

In our development setup there is one publisher with 5 subscribers, all tables in one schema are being replicated. All servers are running pg 13.1, the subscribers are basically all clones of the same system.

Once a month or so we have to clear down most of the tables being replicated and re-populate them from a legacy system, a process that starts with deleting a chunk of data from the table (as defined by part of the key) and then copying that chunk of data across for each table. The size of the data is around 90GB all told.

Every time we do this one or more of the subscribers will get stuck (not always the same ones), looking at the logs on the publisher it shows for the stuck subscriber(s) "could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer".

Looking at the logs on the subscriber(s) it shows duplicate key errors "ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint" but, from the key it shows, it will be a different row on each server (though often the same table).

Deleting the offending row on the subscriber simply makes it then fall over at the next row (so it's obviously more than just one row).

This makes no sense to me, nothing else is writing to the tables on these subscribers and I can't really picture a situation where replication would be trying to write the same data twice.
So far the only solution I have is to drop the bad subscriber(s) and restart replication on them.

Does anyone have any advice or ideas as to why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: If you `TRUNCATE` the tables, how come they contain rows?

Comment: Exactly, the only rows are coming from replication, which is why I am confused that it is coming back with duplicate errors, further compounded by each server coming back with a different result (different error row or worked fine) despite having the same sequence of operations being replicated and starting from the same point.

Comment: Laurenz - thanks for that question, I just reviewed the code that copies from the legacy system and it actually deletes existing chunks (defined by the key) before copying that chunk. I will update my question to reflect this. I do not think this has any particular baring on the issue given how it is so inconsistent across the servers.